# My As3 Flash site will not load properly on a server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hosting

When ran in a local environment the site loads without an issue.
When I attempt to run the site on a remote server / hosting the gallery hangs and doesn't load.

The gallery uses an xml file to draw.

Comment: Did you debug the SWF? Are all files accessible? I'd bet you'd have some naming or path problems. But accessing the SWF with the debugger would definitely help finding the issue. Or an security problem ... but without a stacktrace ... it's guessing at best.

Comment: when i try to access the image (http://resolution2u.com/pics/small/Welcome/1.jpg), i got 404. make sure all the images are uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the names are all lowercase. I know most people think it doesn't matter but it honestly does on some servers. Another thing try not to use spaces in names either. On some servers it causes issues. And depending on where you are hosting it, there should be help and FAQs that usually help when having an issue. You can always ask them what's up they may have different scripts running that will cause you to need to alter your settings or code. But without playing with it myself I'm not sure what help I can give... Wherever you are hosting should help you get it up and running correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Code is extremely case sensitive. I can't believe this simple mistake slided by. I'm going to make all the extensions lowercase to reduce the possibility of this mistake reocurring. Thank you stackoverflow users!! I wish I could post images. But anyways on the Big and small folder it contained.... 1.JPG and 2.jpg on my XML FILE... It referenced 1.JPG AND 2.JPG Because 2.jpg was lowercase in the folder it looked for it but didn't find it.